# Managing JsonObject insead of JSONObject - Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have to make jsonformat as below :

```
[
  "mon":{"start":"1","end":"10"},
  "tue":{"start":"1","end":"10"},
]
```

I must have to use **JsonArray** instead of JSONArray and **JsonObject** instead of JSONObject.

I have tried as below :

```
var mJsonArray=JsonArray()
var jsonObjectMonday:JsonObject=JsonObject()

jsonObjectMonday.addProperty("start",""+minValue.toString())
jsonObjectMonday.addProperty("end",""+maxValue.toString())

mJsonArray.add("mon",jsonObjectMonday)
```

Here, the last line gives me : **None of the function can be called with the specified arguments.**

I must have to pass the key **'mon'** but, getting above issue. **Is there any other method or way available to do so?** **How?**

NOTE : I can do it without '**mon**' and **'tue'** tabs/keys as below :

```
mJsonArray.add(jsonObjectMonday)
```

I want as below :

```
    [
      "mon": {
               "start": "1",
               "end": "10"
             }
   ]
```

Comment: your json will be `[{
  "mon":{"start":"1","end":"10"},
  "tue":{"start":"1","end":"10"},
}]`

Comment: look at the link it' ll help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408284/9908240

Comment: You can't put named fields into json array, so your demanded json format is illegal. You should use an object with two fields instead of array or use an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` is not valid. Try using below to get valid `json`:

```
var mJsonArray= JsonArray()
var jsonObject: JsonObject =JsonObject()

jsonObject.addProperty("start",""+minValue.toString())
jsonObject.addProperty("end",""+maxValue.toString())

var jsonObjectMonday: JsonObject =JsonObject()
jsonObjectMonday.add("mon",jsonObject)

mJsonArray.add(jsonObjectMonday)
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "mon": {
      "start": "1",
      "end": "10"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Edited question : I want as below : I want as below :

        [
          "mon": {
                   "start": "1",
                   "end": "10"
                 }
       ]

Comment: @JaiminModi, What you want is not valid `json`. If you want to set `key` as **mon** then you have to use `JsonObject` and then add that `JsonObject` to `JsonArray` which gives you valid `json` that i mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Check Validation for this json on 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
 There is an error, so i think it must be

```
{
"mon":{"start":"1","end":"10"},
"tue":{"start":"1","end":"10"}
}
```